# Swagger UI always enabled TIBCO BW 6

Tags: swagger-ui, tibco, tibco-business-works

when my application is deploying in production enviroment, I can´t disable the Swagger documentation . This document is always active .
Please, how can I disable swagger documentation?

I have updated the Appnode/config.ini file with the property
 `"bw.rest.docApi.port=7777"` 
to 
`"#bw.rest.docApi.port=7777"` but the swagger is active.

thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding the following to VM arguments (for studio design time) or java.extended.properties (in appnode TRA for runtime) to see if it helps?

```
-DBW_DISABLE_SWAGGER_UI=true
```